# Populate jcombobox from two different mysql data

Tags: java, mysql, jcombobox

I created a jdialog with employee list table with two buttons, the add and details button. The add button will show a blank employee details jdialog for adding new employee while the details button will fill the employee details jdialog based on the selected employee in the list table. The problem is that when I click the details, the jcombobox for department does not show the corresponding data for the selected employee instead it still shows the department list. What I want is that the said jcombobox must show first the department from the selected employee before the department list. How can I achieve that. Here is the code for the jcombobox in question:

```
data = new ProcessDB();
        for(int i = 0; i < data.loadDeptCombo().get(0).size();i++){
            cmbDept.addItem(data.loadDeptCombo().get(1).get(i));
        }

public void loadInfo(String EmpID) throws ParseException{
    data = new ProcessDB();
    cmbDept.addItem(data.getEmpInfo(EmpID).get(4).get(0));
}
```

this is the processdb:

```
public List<List<String>> loadDeptCombo(){
    sql = new String("SELECT * FROM departments ORDER BY Deptname ASC");
    List<List<String>> values =  new ArrayList<>();
    List<String> id = new ArrayList<>();
    List<String> dept = new ArrayList<>();

    try{
        stmt = data.createStatement();
        rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);

        while(rs.next()){
            id.add(String.valueOf(rs.getInt("DeptID")));
            dept.add(rs.getString("Deptname"));
        }
    }catch(SQLException ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    values.add(id);
    values.add(dept);

    return values;
}



 public List<List<String>> getEmpInfo(String EmpID){
    sql = new String("SELECT * FROM workinfo WHERE EmpID = ?");
    List<List<String>> values = new ArrayList<>();
    List<String> empID = new ArrayList<>();
    List<String> lastName = new ArrayList<>();
    List<String> firstName = new ArrayList<>();
    List<String> middleName = new ArrayList<>();
    List<String> department = new ArrayList<>();
    List<String> designation = new ArrayList<>();
    List<String> dateStarted = new ArrayList<>();
    List<String> rate = new ArrayList<>();
    List<String> section = new ArrayList<>();
    List<String> line = new ArrayList<>();
    List<String> admin = new ArrayList<>();

    try{
        pstmt = data.prepareStatement(sql);
        pstmt.setString(1, EmpID);
        rs = pstmt.executeQuery();

        while(rs.next()){
            empID.add(rs.getString("EmpID"));
            lastName.add(rs.getString("Lastname"));
            firstName.add(rs.getString("Firstname"));
            middleName.add(rs.getString("Middlename"));
            department.add(rs.getString("Department"));
            designation.add(rs.getString("Designation"));
            dateStarted.add(String.valueOf(rs.getDate("DateStarted")));
            rate.add(rs.getString("Rate"));
            section.add(rs.getString("Section"));
            line.add(rs.getString("Line"));
            admin.add(rs.getString("Admin"));
        }
    }catch(SQLException ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    values.add(empID);
    values.add(lastName);
    values.add(firstName);
    values.add(middleName);
    values.add(department);
    values.add(designation);
    values.add(dateStarted);
    values.add(rate);
    values.add(section);
    values.add(line);
    values.add(admin);

    return values;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found my solution by arranging the code like this:

```
if(EmpID != ""){
        try {
            data = new ProcessDB();
            loadInfo(EmpID);
            cmbDept.addItem(data.getEmpInfo(EmpID).get(4).get(0));
            cmbRate.addItem(data.getEmpInfo(EmpID).get(7).get(0));

            for(int i = 0; i < data.loadDeptCombo().get(0).size();i++){
                cmbDept.addItem(data.loadDeptCombo().get(1).get(i));
            }

            for(int i = 0;i < data.loadRateCombo().get(0).size();i++){
                cmbRate.addItem(data.loadRateCombo().get(1).get(i));
            }
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }catch(Exception ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }else{
        try{
            data = new ProcessDB();
            for(int i = 0; i < data.loadDeptCombo().get(0).size();i++){
                cmbDept.addItem(data.loadDeptCombo().get(1).get(i));
            }

            for(int i = 0;i < data.loadRateCombo().get(0).size();i++){
                cmbRate.addItem(data.loadRateCombo().get(1).get(i));
            }

        }catch(Exception ex){
            //ex.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        }

    }
```

first reload the data from the table if the string EmpID is not empty followed by loading the default department list and if empty, reload only the default department list in the combobox.